# JSON Serialization: Class name to be picked from annotation

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

Can anybody help me in JSON Serialization. I need to change the qualified class name using Annotation. I don't have to use Map or another class. Name should be picked from Annotation.

-> Annotation I used is

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property ="type")
private Object menu;

-> JSON I'm able to get is

"menu" : [ "**java.util.ArrayList**", [ {
      "name" : "Menu_Test",
      "data" : "Menu_123"
    } ] ],

-> But I want it to be something like this.

"menu" : [ "**list**", [ {
      "name" : "Menu_Test",
      "data" : "Menu_123"
    } ] ],

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` and then you will need to specify the name of each class with additional annotations, for example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ArrayList.class, name = "list")
})
```